# REST best practice, GET a user by userId according to a cluster by clusterId

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I would like to GET a user by userId according to a cluster. I have the same user but in multiple clusters and I need to query it by clusterId

Which of the following URL endpoints is best practice ?

1. [www.example.com/user/{userId}/cluster{clusterId}](http://www.example.com/user/%7BuserId%7D/cluster%7BclusterId%7D)
2. [www.example.com/user/{userId}?cluster={clusterId}](http://www.example.com/user/%7BuserId%7D?cluster=%7BclusterId%7D)

Comment: There is no right or wrong, just personal preferences hence I voted for `Primarily opinion-based`

Comment: Still, since you have a lot of experience with REST, which option would you implement ?

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't matter. If both, users and clusters can exist on their own than simply go for the second option. If a user can only exist in a cluster thatn it would make more sense to use `/clusters/users` and if you want to list only the users of a certain cluster than use something like `/clusters/{clusterId}/users` or whatever you like

Answer (score -1):

First of all, in Rest, you must use plural for your resources, i.e `/users/{userId}` instead of `/user/{userId}`.

To answer your question, I would go with the second one, using query parameters, it offers more flexibility and reuse for other use cases using one endpoint.

Suppose you want to fetch all users no matter the cluster they belong to, if you go with the first one, you would have to create another endpoint, but if you go with second one you would just use `/users/{userId}` without providing a query parameter.

Suppose you want to fetch users of not just one but several clusters, you would provide a `cluster` query parameter with multiple ids separated by a comma, however, if you choose the first one, you'll have to create another endpoint.

Comment: `you must use plural` - NO! It is totaly unimportant how the URI is setup. It is just a pointer to a resource. The semantic of the URI should be kept in the relation name and not in the URI.

Comment: Using plural nouns is for consistency. If we go with singular nouns, the endpoint `/user` gives the illusion that it will return one user, because the resource name used suggests so, duh!. plus having `/user/{id}` makes no sense. 
This isn't my opinion, this is a best practice, look at this thread's url, SO is using `/questions` not `question`. [REST principles](http://apiguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_and_publish/use_RESTful_urls.html)

Comment: As REST is not a protocol there is simply no right or wrong! I admit that you should use a consistent naming convention. In regards to REST though the URI design is not important at all. A RESTful client should not interpret an URI at all to decide wheter to invoke it or not but the relation name the URI was returned for. The advantage you gain is simply that the client is not coupled to the API itself but to the media type which suggests how to process the received data. The client just invokes the URI contained in a certain field and ignoring the possible semantic in the URI string at all

Comment: ... hence any particular effort you put into naming your URIs is somehow just a waste in the sense of true REST. An URI like `/afjafjafjaökjaöjf` is just as RESTful as `/api/users/872342`. The latter one is though more meaningful to implementors or users of the API though this also often leads to developers assuming that certain resources return certain data ([*typed* resources](http://soabits.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html)) for implementation simplicity. That the client however will break if the server changes is an other topic they are willing to neglect